# Independence of stationary process and it's derivative.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stationary-processes

Let $X(t)$ be a centred stationary gaussian process on the reals, with differentiable sample paths, with covariance function $r(t)$

Are $X(0)$ and $X'(0)$ independent? Why?

Are they independent only when $r'(0)=0$ ?